# Pass parameters to javascript function from property element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript function to control visibility of buttons, which are set depend of value of arguments.

```
function checkStateDropDownLists(avaiable,selected) {
    if (avaiable < 1) {
        document.getElementById("btnAddHouse").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("btnShowDescription").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("btnAddHouse").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("btnShowDescription").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    if (selected < 1) {
        document.getElementById("btnRemoveSelected").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('btnConfirmHouses').style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("btnRemoveSelected").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('btnConfirmHouses').style.visibility = 'visible'
    }
}
```

I call this function in tag script

```
checkStateDropDownLists(document.getElementById("ReservationAvaiableHouses").length, document.getElementById("ReservationSelectedHouses").length);
```

Elements: **ReservationAvaiableHouses** and **ReservationSelectedHouses** are dropdownlists and arguments are quantity of options each of them. Call in this way doesn't any result. Is it the matter of format given arguments or this call of method should be outside head section? Definition of method is in head section.

Html code

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Domek</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div id="housesDropdownLists">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Rodzaje domków", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ReservationAvaiableHouses", Model.AvaiableHouses, new { id = "ReservationAvaiableHouses" })
                    <input type="button" id="btnShowDescription" value="Opis" />
                    <div id="description" style="display:inline-flex">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Wybrane domki", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ReservationSelectedHouses", Model.SelectedHouses, new { id = "ReservationSelectedHouses" })
                    <input type="button" id="btnRemoveSelected" value="Usuń zaznaczenie" onclick="handler(event)" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="button" id="btnAddHouse" value="Dodaj domek" class="btn btn-default"  />
                <input type="submit" id="btnConfirmHouses" value="Potwierdź domki" class="btn btn-default" style="visibility:hidden" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some of your HTML as well?

Comment: HTML has been added.